# Reindexing and filling missing dates in PySpark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Is there a way to fill in the missing column dates and row values in PySpark? Currently, I convert the dataframe to Pandas and reindex there.

```
sdf.show()

+---+----------+----------+----------+
| id|2018-01-01|2018-01-03|2018-01-05|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| 1 |       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|
| 2 |       4.0|       2.0|       0.0|
| 3 |       0.0|       1.0|       1.0|
| 7 |       0.0|       2.0|       9.0|
| 8 |       8.0|       0.0|       0.0|
| 9 |       0.0|       0.0|       3.0|
+---+----------+----------+----------+

idx = pd.date_range('01-01-2018', '01-07-2018').date    
df = sdf.toPandas()
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.reindex(idx, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

I haven't been able to find something similar in PySpark.

Desired output:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|2018-01-01|2018-01-02|2018-01-03|2018-01-04|2018-01-05|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1 |       0.0|       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|       0.0|
| 2 |       4.0|       0.0|       2.0|       0.0|       0.0|
| 3 |       0.0|       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|       1.0|
| 7 |       0.0|       0.0|       2.0|       0.0|       9.0|
| 8 |       8.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|
| 9 |       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       3.0|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lit()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit) to the values in `idx` which re not already present in the dataframe.

Note I have converted the column as string just for testing:

```
ids = [str(i) for i in idx] #may not be required
to_add = [col for col in ids if col not in df.columns]
out = df.select(df.columns+ [lit(0).alias(name) for name in to_add])
out.show()
```

---

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|2018-01-01|2018-01-03|2018-01-05|2018-01-02|2018-01-04|2018-01-06|2018-01-07|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|       0.0|       1.0|       0.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|       4.0|       2.0|       0.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|       0.0|       1.0|       1.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  7|       0.0|       2.0|       9.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  8|       8.0|       0.0|       0.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  9|       0.0|       0.0|       3.0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: **SideNote** : to produce a sorted output you can test: `out.select(sorted(out.columns,key=lambda x: (x!='id',x))).show()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rdd_df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
df_final = rdd_df.toDF(sampleRatio=0.2)
df_final = df_final.withColumn('name_id', df_final['_1'].getItem("column name"))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I've added an example of my desired output for more clarification