# Check if column name in lst is in df.columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to check if any of the columns in checklst is one of the column names in a df and if not, create an empty col with the name in checklst. Not sure what best approach is for this.

```
checklst= ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    for i in checklst:
    if not checklst' in df.columns:
         df = df.withColumn("checklst", F.lit(None))
```

Comment: this is similar: [Reindexing and filling missing dates in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191028/reindexing-and-filling-missing-dates-in-pyspark/61192758#61192758) to what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

```
checklst= ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

for x in checklst:
    if x not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn(x, F.lit(None))
```